# C# Application for Sattelite TV and Logo/scrolls

Tags: c#-4.0, vlc, libvlc

I want to develop an application (basically a media player with additional features). What i want is:

1. Play specified videos ( i.e Local video or satellite TV eg. HBO, NAT GEO etc)
2. Show Logos on top right/left corner
3. Play scrolls ( like news scroll being played on CNN on the bottom of the screen )
4. L-Shaped Ads ( sometimes and on some geographical regions they are played oftenly during cricket matches ). Basically the transmission is skewed to some size. Then the  region freed up by skewing is filled with a L-Shaped advertisement.

Is it possible to implement using libVLC or libVLCnet?

If yes, please i need to know easy to learn way. I am really noob with the libVLC and have some know how with C# .net.

Thanks